# Input icon disappears after validating

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically i know my issue , but I don't know how to re-write it to make it work.

I have icon on the left side of the input field. Icon is created with background-image.

Also i have a validation for the input field. When validation is wrong, then input field change the background to red. It also removes the icon. How can I rewrite the code so the background changes , but also the icon stay there?

I want the icon the stay where it is.

```js
$('#fname').blur(function(e) {
  if (validatefname('fname')) {
    $('#fname').css('background', '#e6f3d1');
  }
  else {
    $('#fname').css('background', '#ffa5a5');
  }
});

function validatefname(fname) {
  var a = document.getElementById(fname).value;
  var filter = (/^([a-zA-Z-+ ]+){3,}$/);
  if (filter.test(a)) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
div#first {
  max-width: 400px;
  height:auto;
  margin: 50px auto 0; 
  padding: 20px 25px; 
  background-color: #FFF;
  color:  #333333;
  border: 2px solid #EEE; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
}

.form {
  text-align: center;
}

input#fname { 
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/8ball_20x20px.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding-left: 35px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px; 
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* for I.E */
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;  /* for Mozilla web browser*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">

  <div class="form">

    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" name="name" required="required" maxlength="45">

  </div>

</div>
```

Here is the `jfiddle` [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/jkdbvpbn/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite easy to fix. Instead of setting 'background' in your jquery, set 'background-color' like this:

```js
$('#fname').blur(function(e) {
        if (validatefname('fname')) {
  $('#fname').css('background-color', '#e6f3d1');
        }
        else {
            $('#fname').css('background-color', '#ffa5a5');
        }
    });
    
    function validatefname(fname) {
    var a = document.getElementById(fname).value;
 var filter = (/^([a-zA-Z-+ ]+){3,}$/);
    if (filter.test(a)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
div#first {
 max-width: 400px;
 height:auto;
 margin: 50px auto 0; 
 padding: 20px 25px; 
 background-color: #FFF;
 color:  #333333;
 border: 2px solid #EEE; 
 border-radius: 5px; 
}

.form {
 text-align: center;
}

input#fname { 
 background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/8ball_20x20px.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 6px;
 border: 1px solid #DADADA;
 margin: 5px 0;
 padding-left: 35px;
 width: 80%;
 height: 30px; 
 font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* for I.E */
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;  /* for Mozilla web browser*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">

   <div class="form">
     
      <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" name="name" required="required" maxlength="45">

   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
$('#fname').css('background', '#e6f3d1');
```

with this:

```
$('#fname').css('background-color', '#e6f3d1');
```

The image disappears, because the background css style overwrites the background-* styles if it is modified later.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `background-color` instead of `background`

```
  if (validatefname('fname')) {
      $('#fname').css('background-color', '#e6f3d1');
   }
    else {

      $('#fname').css('background-color', '#ffa5a5');
   }
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jkdbvpbn/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You've replaced the complete background, but you only want to replace the color:

```
    if (validatefname('fname')) {
      $('#fname').css('background-color', '#e6f3d1');
    } else {
      $('#fname').css('background-color', '#ffa5a5');
    }
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jkdbvpbn/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-color` css property to set only the background color

```
$('#fname').blur(function(e) {
        if (validatefname('fname')) {
  $('#fname').css('background-color', '#e6f3d1');
        }
        else {
            $('#fname').css('background-color', '#ffa5a5');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

in your JQ use `background-color` instead of `background`

using `background` only will overwrite all background properties you've set initally in your CSS

click on the link below to see result. let me know if it works.

```js
$('#fname').blur(function(e) {
        if (validatefname('fname')) {
  $('#fname').css('background-color', '#e6f3d1');
        }
        else {
            $('#fname').css('background-color', '#ffa5a5');
        }
    });
    
    function validatefname(fname) {
    var a = document.getElementById(fname).value;
 var filter = (/^([a-zA-Z-+ ]+){3,}$/);
    if (filter.test(a)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
div#first {
 max-width: 400px;
 height:auto;
 margin: 50px auto 0; 
 padding: 20px 25px; 
 background-color: #FFF;
 color:  #333333;
 border: 2px solid #EEE; 
 border-radius: 5px; 
}

.form {
 text-align: center;
}

input#fname { 
 background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/8ball_20x20px.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 6px;

 border: 1px solid #DADADA;
 margin: 5px 0;
 padding-left: 35px;
 width: 80%;
 height: 30px; 
 font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* for I.E */
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;  /* for Mozilla web browser*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">

   <div class="form">
     
      <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" name="name" required="required" maxlength="45">

   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the quick solution is using border instaed of background color, try this

```
$('#fname').css('border', '2px solid red');
```

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Sarathv15/jkdbvpbn/4/) is the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
background: rgb(255, 165, 165);
```

use

```
background-color: rgb(255, 165, 165);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are change the background property, but you want to chage only background-color property.

`$('#fname').css('background-color', '#e6f3d1');`

Answer (score 0):

i think it is overwriting the background. try  `$('#fname').css('background',...` to  `$('#fname').css('background-color',`

Answer (score 0):

try to create 2 class css

```
.red{
background:'red';
background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/8ball_20x20px.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 6px;
}

.green{
background:'green';
background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/8ball_20x20px.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 6px;
}
```

and your js code will be :

```
$('#fname').blur(function(e) {
        if (validatefname('fname')) {
  $('#fname').removeClass('red')addClass('green');
        }
        else {
  $('#fname').removeClass('green').addClass('red');
        }
    });
```